# Equivalent to Guice + RequestScope in Play Framework 2.4 (Scala)

Tags: scala, playframework, guice

I am currently injecting some Service classes into Controller classes in Play Framework 2.4.  Each service class has a reference to one or more Repository classes that access the database.  It looks something like this:

```scala
class AccountRepositoryImpl @Inject() (db: DB) extends AccountRepository {
    def find(id: Long): Future[Option[Account]] = // ...

    def insert(account: Account): Future[Long] = // ...
}

class AccountServiceImpl @Inject() (
    val accountRepository: AccountRepository) extends AccountService {

    // ...   
}


class AccountController @Inject() (
    val accountService: AccountService,
    val someOtherService: SomeOtherService) extends Controller {

    def signup: Action[JsValue] = Action.async(parse.json) { implicit request =>
        val jsonSignup: JsResult[SignUp] = request.body.validate[SignUp]

        for {
           userid <- accountService.insert(signUp.Value)
           somethingElse <- someOtherService.doMoreSetup(userid)
           // ...
        } yield {
           // ...
        }
}

class ApiModule extends AbstractModule with ScalaModule {

    def configure(): Unit = {
        bind[DB].to[DBImpl]
        bind[AccountRepository].to[AccountRepositoryImpl]
        bind[AccountService].to[AccountServiceImpl]
        bind[SomeOtherService].to[SomeOtherServiceImpl]
    }
}
```

This works fine, but now I would like to add the ability to handle database transactions across Service classes.  To do that I was planning to write an ActionBuilder that can wrap the request in a transaction:

```scala
class Transaction @Inject()(
    val db: DB) {

    object TransactionAction extends ActionBuilder[Request] {
        def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (Request[A]) => Future[Result]): Future[Result] = {
            db.startTransaction()
            val result = block(request)
            db.commit() // todo: put rollback logic here
            result
        }
    }
}
```

To do this, I need to share the same DB object among all the other injected objects, and I don't see a way to do that easily in Guice---
it doesn't seem like there's a way to inject a single object in `RequestScope`.

So my plan was to use Guice's `@Assisted` notation and create some factories, e.g.:

```scala
class AccountRepositoryImpl @Inject() (@Assisted db: DB) extends AccountRepository {
    // ...
}

trait AccountRepositoryFactory {
   def create(db: DB): AccountRepository
}

class ApiModule extends AbstractModule with ScalaModule {

   def configure(): Unit = {
       // ...

       install(new FactoryModuleBuilder()
           .implement(classOf[AccountRepository],classOf[AccountRepositoryImpl])
           .build(classOf[AccountRepositoryFactory])

       install(new FactoryModuleBuilder()
           .implement(classOf[AccountService],classOf[AccountServiceImpl])
           .build(classOf[AccountServiceFactory])


   )
```

... and then replace the injected Traits with Factories and inject the DB into the controller.

I think this will allow me to share a single DB instance among injected objects, but it seems like a lot of boilerplate, and it's extra work to write tests.  Is there a smarter way of doing this in Play Framework?

Comment: I'm using Play with Java. There I'm doing something like `Http.Context.current().args.put(key, value)` and `Http.Context.current().args.get(key)` to have an request scope.

Comment: @kris I haven't tried it but I see that someone created a Guice RequestScope annotation using `Http.Context.current()` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25626264/how-to-use-play-frameworks-request-and-session-scope-in-google-guice#answer-34981902).  I don't know how it would work with Scala Futures, though.

Comment: ... someone else mentions the same caveat about sharing a connection among threads in futures [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22527160/database-transactions-in-play-framework-scala-applications-anorm#answer-22534329).  Maybe what I'm trying to do is not a good idea....